# Istio gateway, connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a bare-metal kubernetes cluster, which use metallb as ELB.

I am tring to expose a service with istio `gateway`, but facing **connection refused** problem. I am new to istio, please help to check my manifests.

versions:

```
Kubernetes clsuter version: 1.27
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57 
cni-dockerd : cri-dockerd-0.3.4
OS: CentOS 7
MetalLB v0.13.10
```

problem:

**Note**: `ceph-dashboard.xxx.com` is in /etc/hosts file

```
[ggfan@fedora rook]$ curl -vvv https://ceph-dashboard.xxx.com/
*   Trying 172.28.6.200:443...
* connect to 172.28.6.200 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to ceph-dashboard.xxx.com port 443 after 2 ms: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ceph-dashboard.xxx.com port 443 after 2 ms: Connection refused
```

the service:

```
Name:              rook-ceph-mgr-dashboard
Namespace:         rook-ceph
Labels:            app=rook-ceph-mgr
                   rook_cluster=rook-ceph
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=rook-ceph-mgr,mgr_role=active,rook_cluster=rook-ceph
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.102.185.38
IPs:               10.102.185.38
Port:              http-dashboard  7000/TCP
TargetPort:        7000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.228.168:7000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

gateway and virtual service definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ceph-dashboard-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 7000
      name: http-dashboard
      protocol: http-web
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: lecerts
    hosts:
    - ceph-dashboard.bgzchina.com
    
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ceph-dashboard-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "ceph-dashboard.bgzchina.com"
  gateways:
  - ceph-dashboard-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 7000
        host: rook-ceph-mgr-dashboard
```

lecerts is tls secret created from certs from let's encrypt:

```
[ggfan@fedora ingress-nginx]$ kubectl describe secret lecerts -n rook-ceph
Name:         lecerts
Namespace:    rook-ceph
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  5238 bytes
tls.key:  241 bytes
```

the istio ingressgateway service:

```
West Farmer
  上午 10:50
Hi, I am tring to expose a service with gateway, but I am facing connection refused problem, any idea ?
the service :
Name:              rook-ceph-mgr-dashboard
Namespace:         rook-ceph
Labels:            app=rook-ceph-mgr
                   rook_cluster=rook-ceph
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=rook-ceph-mgr,mgr_role=active,rook_cluster=rook-ceph
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.102.185.38
IPs:               10.102.185.38
Port:              http-dashboard  7000/TCP
TargetPort:        7000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.228.168:7000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
gateway and virtual service:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ceph-dashboard-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 7000
      name: http-dashboard
      protocol: http-web
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: lecerts
    hosts:
    - ceph-dashboard.bgzchina.com
    
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ceph-dashboard-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "ceph-dashboard.bgzchina.com"
  gateways:
  - ceph-dashboard-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 7000
        host: rook-ceph-mgr-dashboard
istio-ingressgateway:
[ggfan@fedora rook]$ kubectl -n istio-system describe svc istio-ingressgateway
Name:                     istio-ingressgateway
Namespace:                istio-system
Labels:                   app=istio-ingressgateway
                          install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource=unknown
                          install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace=istio-system
                          istio=ingressgateway
                          istio.io/rev=default
                          operator.istio.io/component=IngressGateways
                          operator.istio.io/managed=Reconcile
                          operator.istio.io/version=1.18.1
                          release=istio
Annotations:              metallb.universe.tf/ip-allocated-from-pool: default-pool
Selector:                 app=istio-ingressgateway,istio=ingressgateway
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.98.117.31
IPs:                      10.98.117.31
LoadBalancer Ingress:     172.28.6.200
Port:                     status-port  15021/TCP
TargetPort:               15021/TCP
NodePort:                 status-port  31967/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.228.161:15021
Port:                     http2  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 http2  31509/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.228.161:8080
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30320/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.228.161:8443
Port:                     tcp  31400/TCP
TargetPort:               31400/TCP
NodePort:                 tcp  32554/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.228.161:31400
Port:                     tls  15443/TCP
TargetPort:               15443/TCP
NodePort:                 tls  32483/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.228.161:15443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                From             Message
  ----    ------        ----               ----             -------
  Normal  nodeAssigned  45m                metallb-speaker  announcing from node "k8sc01wn03" with protocol "layer2"
  Normal  nodeAssigned  28m (x4 over 88m)  metallb-speaker  announcing from node "k8sc01mn01" with protocol "layer2"
```

Comment: If you are using certificates, use [file mount](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/) to provide certificates to the isito-ingressgateway. It is possible to mount multiple certificates following [this guide](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-multiple-hosts) however the istio-ingressgateway pods need to be re-created to pick up new certs.

Comment: Refer to \[Troubleshooting the Ceph Dashboard\](https://documentation.suse.com/ses/7.1/html/ses-all/bp-troubleshooting-dashboard.html), which may help to resolve your issue.<br>

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy I can access ceph dashboard with port forwading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please match your application gateway ports with istio-ingressgateway service https port information.  There is no 7000 port in ingress gateway service defined.

Below information in application gateway has to be matched information in istio-ingressgateway service https information.

```
- port:
  number: 443
  name: https
  protocol: HTTPS
```

Answer (score 1):

**Istio Gateway Connection refused might be caused due to any of the below reasons:**

1. The istio-ingressgateway will not accept connections on a given port if it does not have a [listener](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/listener/v3/listener.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-listener-v3-listener) configured for that port. (Istio will configure the proxy to listen on the ports, ensure that external traffic to the ports are allowed into the mesh).
2. The Gateway object is specifying a **credentialName** and the [Secret Discovery Service (SDS)](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/security/secret) is not enabled. For more details see **credentialName** in the [Gateway TLS Settings reference](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#ServerTLSSettings).

Check the Gateway object is created, you can see the **credentialName** parameter is specified like the following:

```
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - httpbin.example.com
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: httpbin-credential
      mode: SIMPLE
```

You can search the pilot logs for more details.

To check if SDS is enabled, you can inspect the istio ConfigMap on the istio-system namespace. If the sdsUdsPath is empty or not set, it means SDS is not enabled.

To obtain the value you can run the below command:

```
kubectl get configmap istio -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.data}' \| grep sdsUdsPath
```

If it is set, the output will be as follows:

```
sdsUdsPath: unix:/etc/istio/proxy/SDS
```

If SDS is disabled, the value will be empty as follows:

```
sdsUdsPath:
```

Comment: for first reason, how do I verify the listener is up and running ?

Comment: This can be verified by inspecting **pilot logs** and searching for the istio-ingressgateway there. It shows that there are listeners configured for the istio-ingressgateway.

Comment: do you mean istiod pod logs ?

Comment: Run this command you will get **$ kubectl logs -n istio-system $(kubectl get -n istio-system pod -l istio=pilot -o jsonpath='{.items\[0\].metadata.name}') -c discovery --tail 50 \| grep istio-ingressgateway \| grep listeners**

Comment: only found this: `2023-07-25T02:52:21.649996Z info gateway omitting listener "0.0.0.0_7000" due to: must have more than 0 chains in listener "0.0.0.0_7000"`

Comment: with your command, nothing found.

Comment: Can you run the command & provide the output: **kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254653/discussion-between-westfarmer-and-veera-nagireddy).